# Radio Button for Color Option of product

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Because products are available on other color, I'm planning to add an option or radio button to select a specific color for ordering the product. The problem is I can't figure it out on how to do it like this.
Here's the image.
[http://imgur.com/a/wm6Ny](https://imgur.com/a/wm6Ny)

I'm using bootstrap.
Thank you :)

My code

```
  <div class="colors">
            <ul>
                <li><input type="radio" name="color" style="background-color:#222"><span></span></li>
                <li><input type="radio" name="color" style="background-color:#6e8cd5"><span></span></li>
                <li><input type="radio" name="color" style="background-color:#44c28d"><span></span></li>
            </ul> 
        </div>
```

Comment: your image isn't working

Answer (score 1):

Going off of your existing markup I believe you're looking for something like this:

```css
.colors ul{list-style:none; padding:0; margin: 0;}

.colors li{margin: 0 20px 0 0; display: inline-block;}

.colors label{cursor: pointer;}

.colors input{display:none;}

.colors input[type="radio"]:checked + .swatch{box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px white;}

.swatch{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 30px;
  width:30px;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0 ;
  border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
}
```

```html
<div class="colors">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="color" value="black">
        <span class="swatch" style="background-color:#222"></span> Black
      </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="color" value="blue">
        <span class="swatch" style="background-color:#6e8cd5"></span> Blue
      </label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="color" value="green">
        <span class="swatch" style="background-color:#44c28d"></span> Green
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul> 
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vkxts1af/1/

Comment: Yes! Thanks a lot @Serg Chernata.

Comment: Last question how to make it horizontally ?